# data.table error in r related to referencing certain objects

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following example

```
a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
b <- 1:6
c <- c("a","E","D","C","B","A")
d <- 10:15

dt1 <- data.table("ID" = b,"code_a" = a,"code_c" = c, "code_d" = d)
dt2 <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_c" = c, "code_d" = d )
dt3 <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_d" = d)
merged_list <- list(dt1,dt2,dt3)
output <- merged_list[[1]][merged_list[[1]][,2] != merged_list[[1]][,3]]
```

The Error test reads as follows:

> Error in `[.data.table`(merged_list[[1]], merged_list[[1]][, 2] != merged_list[[1]][,  : 
>     i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.

Here I want to get the output for first item in `merged_list`, which is a `data.table`, but given condition where the second item in the `data.table` must not equal to the third item in the `data.table`

I am unsure why the above doesn't work, but if i use `$code_a` and `$code_c` instead of `[,2]` and `[,3]` it works. I would not like to use `$` referencing because it does not work nicely in a loop.

Expected Output:

```
output
#     ID code_a code_c code_d
# 1:  2      b      E     11
# 2:  3      c      D     12
# 3:  4      d      C     13
# 4:  5      e      B     14
# 5:  6      f      A     15
```

As only the first row has `code_a` equals to `code_c` so that is removed. Thanks for the help. My main objective here is to not use `$code_a` as i cant put it in a for loop which gives me `code_a`, `code_b`, `code_c` etc. etc. Any help into what I did wrong and how I can solve this issue is greatly appreciated. And sorry for the non informative title, I am not exactly sure what this kind of problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because as the error message suggest the comparison returns a matrix.

```
merged_list[[1]][,2] != merged_list[[1]][,3]
#     code_a
#[1,]  FALSE
#[2,]   TRUE
#[3,]   TRUE
#[4,]   TRUE
#[5,]   TRUE
#[6,]   TRUE

class(merged_list[[1]][,2] != merged_list[[1]][,3])
#[1] "matrix"
```

Turn it into a vector and it should work

```
merged_list[[1]][c(merged_list[[1]][,2] != merged_list[[1]][,3])]

#   ID code_a code_c code_d
#1:  2      b      E     11
#2:  3      c      D     12
#3:  4      d      C     13
#4:  5      e      B     14
#5:  6      f      A     15
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what i wanted. I have an additional question tho. If I let `z <- 1 ` and `merged_list[[z]][,4-z]`, so what i want to do is obtain the first `data.table` in the list and take the 3rd column of it, it gives me an answer of `3` as a `numeric` answer, how might I do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kazusa12345 You need to add `with = FALSE`, do `merged_list[[z]][, (4-z), with = FALSE]`